# How do I make PeerJS work on the real world?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn, peerjs

I managed to connect two browsers on two separate computers at my house using PeerJS, everything is working fine as long both clients are uder the same internet. However, when I tried testing with someone outside the connection would not open. The receiver gets the sender's ID, but the sender cannot open the connection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRDMR.jpg

I start by creating a default Peer object on both clients

```
peer = new Peer(randomId);
```

and I create the connection by pasting the id from one client to the other client via a html input

```
conn = peer.connect(textinput.value);
```

Comment: Did you set up STUN/TURN server configurations?

Comment: i am using the default as in the documentation

{ 'iceServers': [{ 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] }